# Clone a Windows2000 System Disk

Tags: windows, hard-drive, clone

I have an old Windows 2K PC which needs to be kept going for a few more years. It cannot be replaced by a modern PC because of driver availability issues so I want to create a clone of the HDD as insurance. Current releases of clone software like Acronis don't support W2K so can't use a direct method for this. Has anyone done something similar recently or have any suggestions how to go about it? Thanks

a) Tried to load an older version of Acronis onto W2K but it refused. b) have just asked some of the major cloning software cos for suggestions but no useful replies.

Comment: I think that the best route would be to boot with some boot USB and clone it like that (so you're not dependent in W2K supporting the software.)

Comment: You can do that with Acronis (https://kb.acronis.com/content/65508?ckattempt=1) or other solutions (I like Macrium Reflect Free https://knowledgebase.macrium.com/display/KNOW72/Creating+rescue+media)

Comment: Get a Windows 2000 CD from a legitimate source on Ebay with right of return. Make a Virtual Machine of 2000 using a proper VM App (VMware) and be sure your software runs in that environment. That makes you less dependent on hardware. I have a Windows 2000 VM

Comment: How about [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) and just doing a sector copy of the entire drive? That way you don't have to care about the tool supporting the older versions of NTFS...

Comment: "major cloning software cos"? What should that be? Please use plain English language that can be understood on the whole planet. 
Bad language contributions get a time penalty from me - no answer or a delayed answer from me. Thank you for your understanding!

Comment: Hi All, sorry for late response, I was expecting to get emails when anybody posted but nothing turned up until yesterday. Thanks to all for the helpful suggestions, I'll have to go away now and see which to try first although they all look sensible. p.s. 'cos' was a lazy abbreviation for 'companies'.